# Creating several JSON files with a cronjob (PHP-file)

Tags: php, json, cron

Quite important, I don't really know how to write PHP, but I have some experience with JavaScript.

I created a PHP file which scrapes a website and writes the data to different (22) JSON files. If I visit the file from my browser the script does what it supposed to do and it creates the 22 JSON files.

Nou I wanted to use the cronjob functionality to run the script daily. I tried it and I received a mail with the echo's I normally would see in my browser, so I could say the script runs. The script has to run to post the echo's. But there are no JSON-files created.

Why doesn't my script create the files when I run it via a cronjob?

I'm using this function to write the files:

```
function write_to_file($value,$content) {
    echo "Done<br>";
    $file = fopen($value.".json","w");
    fwrite($file,$content);
    fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: That's going to depend on `$value`.

Comment: Where did you look for the files? When you run a script from `cron`, its working directory will be your home directory, not the webserver's directory.

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar suggested, the files are in my home directory. Thanks!